# Но(,) мне кажется, они что-то напутали

Tags: запятые, выбор-варианта

Если поставить запятую, *мне кажется* будет вводным сочетанием, а если оставить только вторую запятую, *кажется* будет членом предложения с пропущенным *что.* Мне ближе второй вариант с одной запятой. *Чем всё-таки определяется выбор?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что выбор может основываться на *контексте*. Вариант без первой запятой наиболее вероятен и соответствует противопоставлению своего *мнения* (но я думаю вот что) чему-то из ранее сказанного.

> По большинству пунктов они высказывались убедительно. Но мне кажется, [что] они
>   что-то напутали.

Вариант с обособлением выражает категорическое несогласие с чем-то, но в риторических целях категоричность дипломатично "разбавлена" вводным выражением; в устной форме требуется также интонационная пауза в месте первой запятой.

> Они утверждают, что я совершил прогул. Но, мне кажется, они что-то
>   напутали.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!